# Npm can't install node-sass

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

When I install npm on my project Angular.
There is an failed install of node-sass.
And after it's impossible to run `ng serve`.

```
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I tried the command:

```
npm install
npm update
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> install by fore it

```
npm install -f node-sass
```

> or

```
yarn add node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and turned out install scripts were disabled. Node Sass installs some binaries in addition to the NPM module, so install scripts need to be enabled.

Try with running `npm i --ignore-scripts=false`